# Get Pivot Table data into userform VBA

Tags: vba, pivot-table, user-forums

I am trying to fill out a userform with data from an existing Pivot table.
If you see the included image you can see a selection of the pivot table.

[image: Pivot table view - Picture]

In column “A” I have “week number”  in Column “B” I have “Booking number”

I have managed to list all the “week number” (A) in a combobox by doing the following.

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

SendMailWindow.ComboBox_booking.Clear

pt.PivotSelect Name:="Uge nr.[All]", Mode:=xlLabelOnly, UseStandardName:=True
For Each c In Selection
If c <> "" Then
   SendMailWindow.ComboBox_Uge.AddItem c.Value
End If
Next c
```

My problem now is that I want to have another combobox showing only the “Booking number” from column “B” there are within the select “weeknumber” that the user selects in the first Combobox.

In other words I want to filter Combobox no. 2 so that it only shows booking numbers from the selected week.

Hope one of you have an idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This would be much simpler if you changed the PivotTable Layout to Tablular (or made a copy of the PivotTable, and changed the copy's layout). Then you could simply use the type of syntax at https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

In Jon's example, he does this:
`Intersect(pt.PivotFields("Years").Pivotitems("2004").DataRange.EntireRow, pt.PivotFields("Order Date").DataRange).Select`

[image]

In your case, that would translate to something like:
`Intersect(pt.PivotFields("Week Number").Pivotitems(SomeVariable).DataRange.EntireRow, pt.PivotFields("Booking Number").DataRange).Select`